# Click on element and stopPropagation() for another one

Tags: javascript

I have two events: A button event and a container event. I want to apply `stopPropagation()` for container function, when I click on button. How to do this in vanilla js?

Now when I click on button `#btn` two functions will called. My goal is, when I click on button `#btn`, the code for #btn should only run. Click on div with id `#container` shall do it the same.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    console.log('click on btn')
})
const container = document.getElementById('container');
container.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    console.log('click on container')
})
```

```css
#container {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
       <button id="btn">click</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Element.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to detect click outside or inside specific element

check this example

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    console.log('click on btn')
})
const container = document.getElementById('container');
container.addEventListener('click', (e)=> {
  if(!e.target.closest('#btn')){
    console.log('click on container')
  }
})
```

```css
#container {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
       <button id="btn">click</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add [event.stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) in your btn click handler

```
btn.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
        console.log('click on btn')
        event.stopPropagation()
})
```